# Angular 2 String[]

Tags: angular, typescript, object

i'm using Angular2 / TypeScript and want to create an array (or object?) of the following Structure:

{ "names" : [ "Steven", "John" ] }

I want to be able to add several more names, maybe with push?
The names are only available as strings.

I guess this is an object and not a simple string array. but how do I realize that?

Comment: Such questions are not a good fit for StackOverflow. You need to learn prgramming, JavaScript and TypeScript. Read a good book. Or a few good ones. You should know what a string, an array, and an object are.

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to add a new name to the list you can do something like this:

```
let myList = { "names" : [ "Steven", "John" ] };
myList.names.push("Bob");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own interfaces to keep everything typesafe. You could create yours like this

```
interface MyInterface {
  names: string[]
}

const myNames : MyInterface = {
  names: ['John', 'Steven']
}
myNames.names.push('New guy')
```